# Как при открытии страницы добавить элементы в переменную на vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Мне нужно при открытии сайта получать некий result с сайта https://numia.ru/api/getMessages?offset=0, я делаю это , все приходит, но никак не могу записать в переменную.

```
<template>
    <div>{{messages}}</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'


export default{
    data(){
        return {
            messages : ''

        }
    },
    mounted(){
        
        this.messages = this.getMessages()
    },

    methods:{
        getMessages(){
            let arr = []
            axios.get('https://numia.ru/api/getMessages?offset=0').then((response =>{
            if (response.data === "OOPS! TRY AGAIN!"){
            return '123'
            }
            console.log(response.data.result)
            return response.data.result

    
}))
            
        }

    }

}
    
    
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default{
    data(){
        return {
            messages : ''
        };
    },
    mounted(){
        this.getMessages();
    },
    methods:{
        getMessages(){
            let arr = [];
            axios.get('https://numia.ru/api/getMessages?offset=0').then((response =>{
              if (response.data === "OOPS! TRY AGAIN!"){
                this.messages = '123';
              }
              this.messages = response.data.result;
           }))
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить разницу между вашим кодом и кодом ТС-а?

Comment: Дело в том, что функция getMessages ничего не возвращает. Оба return находились внутри анонимной функции. Проще сделать прямое присвоение переменной message когда придут данные. Тем более, что эта переменная реактивная, и изменения в ней сразу же отразятся на странице.